# Error linking module in ocaml

Tags: string, module, include, ocaml

I am a complete beginner with Ocaml programming and I am having trouble linking a module into my program. Actually I am doing some regular expression checking and I have written a function that basically tokenizes a string based on a separator string using the [Str module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Str.html) . So i use the functions defined in the library like this:

```
Str.regexp_string /*and so on*/
```

However, when I try to compile the ml file, I get an error suggesting that I have an undefined global **Str** . We use *List* functions by typing in List.length and so on just like I did for Str without having to explicitly include the specific module. I tried

```
open Str;;
include Str;; /*None of these work and I still get the same error*/
```

However if in the toplevel I use

```
load "str.cma" /*Then the program works without problems*/
```

I want to include the module in the ml file because I have to in the end link 3 cmo's to get the final executable(which is not run in the toplevel). I know this is a really basic question but I am having trouble solving it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to add anything in your file foo.ml.
You do need to tell the compiler where to find the Str module when compiling foo.ml . To do  so, add it to the command line used to compile foo.ml:

```
ocamlc str.cma foo.ml
```

or

```
ocamlopt str.cmxa foo.ml
```

`List` and other modules from the standard library are accessible by default, so you don't need to tell the compiler about those often used modules.

Comment: I don't think your solution would work because he mentions that he wants to link the ".cmo" files ultimately generated. So if I try and compile a simple that uses some functions of the "Str" module and compile it like you said. If i load the ".cmo" in the toplevel, I still get an error saying undefined global Str

Comment: The question is about linking a standalone program. The answer for toplevel is slightly different. In toplevel, you can load Str by saying `#load "str.cma"`.

Comment: ... or invoking the `ocaml` toplevel with `ocaml str.cma`.

Comment: simply adding  "str" in "libraries" works for dune btw

Answer (score 2):

Just add `str` to the `libraries` field of your `dune` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use '-cclib ' compiler directive.
The module name shouldn't include the file ending like .cma.
Below is what I did when trying to use the unix and threads modules.
I think you need to use some combination of the 'custom' and 'cclib' compiler directives.

ocamlc -custom unix.cma threa.ml -cclib -lunix

Look at chapter 7 of this book for help:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora063.html

And look at coverage of compiler directives here:
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual022.html#c:camlc

Answer (score 0):

```
ocamlc calc.ml str.cma -o calc
File "calc.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while linking calc.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Str'
```

Code is very simple, to cut down scruff.

```
let split_into_words s = 
    Str.split ( Str.regexp "[ \n\t]+") s ;;

let _ = 
    split_into_words "abc def ghi" ;;
```

On ocaml 4.0.2. Obviously, there is a problem here, but I am too much of a beginner to understand what it is. From toplevel it seems work fine with #load "str.cma", so there is something here we don't understand. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: You need to put `str.cma` before `calc.ml`.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to solve this problem with `Std`? I'm having the same issue here, but just with `Std`